# Project facet Java version 1.7 is not supported

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I know similar issues has been posted already in SO but unfortunately none of them helped actually.

**Facing :**

> Project facet Java version 1.7 is not supported

**Current Environment :**

Server : Tomcat 7

JDK and JRE :1.6

Eclipse : JUNO

And as per the doc it seems like Tomcat 7 should support JDK 6

Ref : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/building.html

I checked JRE which my project pointing to

> Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JRE

and its pointing to `JRE1.6`.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: is jdk 7 installed? if so did you try changing the jre version eclipse is currently pointed to?

Comment: No i only have JDK 6 and JDK 6 should work with Tomcat 7 right ?

Comment: "Project facet Java version 1.7 is not supported" is what you are facing ... if you don't have JDK 7 how will the the required facet be supported

Comment: Check your Project Settings in Eclipse, perhaps 1.7 is configured there...

Comment: @Tom I Already mentioned my Project settings and its pointing to 1.6

Comment: That's not what I mean, Facet != JRE Settings ... Right Click on Project => Properties => Tabpage Project Facets...

Comment: @Tom It was 1.7..i changed it to 1.6 and it worked :)...Add it as Answer plz and Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facet != JRE Settings ... Right Click on Project => Properties => Tabpage Project Facets...

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Project -> Properties ->  Project Facets
Your project Java version here should be same as Java compiler version
Right Click on Project -> Properties ->  Java Compiler

Based on your input that you want to use JDK 1.16, same should be the version of your Java Compiler and Project Facet Java version.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the java version of your run time (server)environment

In eclipse, goto Windows->Preferences->server->run time environment->select the server on the right side window->edit->In java home->select jdk1.7.0_79 path->finish